# Could not open library '/usr/lib/libmecab.so.2': /usr/lib/libmecab.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mecab

when i tried to start my rails server i got an error related to mecab
So i followed below given instruction to install mecab and it was installed successfully
i checked the version of mecab

while installing mecab followed steps are

```
1. gem install natto
2. sudo apt-get install mecab libmecab-dev
3. sudo apt-get install mecab-ipadic-utf8
4. mecab --version
5. sudo find / -name libmecab.so*

    this gives an error of permission denied

6. echo 'export MECAB_PATH=/usr/lib/libmecab.so.2' >> ~/.bash_profile
7. source ~/.bash_profile
```

After all, this when I tried to start rails server I got below given error

```
/home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ffi-1.9.14/lib/ffi/library.rb:147:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library '/usr/lib/libmecab.so.2': /usr/lib/libmecab.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (LoadError)
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ffi-1.9.14/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `map'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ffi-1.9.14/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `ffi_lib'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/natto-1.1.1/lib/natto/binding.rb:64:in `<module:Binding>'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/natto-1.1.1/lib/natto/binding.rb:6:in `<module:Natto>'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/natto-1.1.1/lib/natto/binding.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/natto-1.1.1/lib/natto/natto.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/natto-1.1.1/lib/natto.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /home/admin123/WFSGo/myproject/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/admin123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Where is the library? On Ubuntu it's installed into `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmecab.so`. What does `mecab-config --libs` return?

Comment: @Casper it returns ```-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmecab -lstdc++```

Comment: Ok, so I don't think you need to export MECAB_PATH at all. It should work without it. But if you do, it should point to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmecab.so` instead.

Comment: but i am not able to start rails server

Comment: Try `export MECAB_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmecab.so` and then `rails server`. Still same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ununtu the mecab lib is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmecab.so`. So this should work:

```
export MECAB_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmecab.so
rails server
```

Comment: @Savan Edit your `.bash_profile` and add it on the last line. That will run it for you every time you log in.

Comment: Actually I think you have your old `MECAB_PATH` in your `.bash_profile` already. You set it as you describe it in your question. It may be enough to delete that line from your profile file. Then log out and back in, and see if it works. If not, then add the line from my answer, which will make it permanent.